# Exception on new ServerSocket: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am Trying to Send Some Details over Socket Along With a File over OutPutStream , But I receive this Exception :

```
 Exception on new ServerSocket: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 
 00BABB8D
```

here is my ClientSide Code :

```
ObjectInputStream  sInput = null;       // to read from the socket
ObjectOutputStream sOutput = null;     // to write on the socket
Socket socket = null;

try {  
           Log.i("Images","in the async");  
           socket = new Socket(HOST, 1600);  
           System.out.println(socket);  
           System.out.println("Connecting...");  
           Log.i("Images","in the service"+filepath+"");    
           Log.i("Images","filepath in the async "+""+filepath+"");
           File fil=new File(filepath);  
             System.out.println(fil);


               System.out.println(fil.getName());  


           OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();    
           DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);   


           dos.writeInt(1);  

                 dos.writeUTF(fil.getName());  


                 int filesize = (int) fil.length();  
                 dos.writeInt(filesize);  

                 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(dos);
                 oos.writeObject("Hey !");
                  // Here is the packet im trying to send along

           byte [] buffer = new byte [filesize];  

           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fil.toString());    
           BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);    

           //Sending file name and file size to the server    
           bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length); //This line is important  
           dos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);     

           fis.close();
           dos.flush();   
          .
          .
          .
```

and my ServerSide :

```
   int fileSize = 0;
                        try {
                            fileSize = clientData.read();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }        
                         fileSize = (fileSize > 0) ? fileSize :    
 0;                                                                      // guard   
 against 
 negatives.
                        List<File> files = new ArrayList<>(fileSize);          
 //store     list of filename from client directory        // Using List and <>
                        List<Integer> sizes = new ArrayList<>(fileSize);        
 //store     file size from client 
                      //Start to accept those filename from server

                        for (int count=0;count < fileSize;count ++){  
                            File ff = null;
                            try {
                                ff = new File(clientData.readUTF());
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }  
                            files.add(ff);  

                            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(in);
                            try {
                                String Request = (String) ois.readObject();
                            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            //here is where im trying to read the packet

                            System.out.println(Request);
```

I appreciate if any one can Help me about What am i Doing wrong Guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't futz around with multiple types of input and output stream. Use the object streams for everything. There are numerous reasons for this, but in this case the problem is introducing an ObjectOutputStream in the middle of the conversation.

Comment: may i ask if it causes serious problems?

Comment: @reza It causes *this* problem.